# c++ access violation at initialising DX

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, access-violation, directx-9

I intended to create a window and initialise Direct9 but I found VS2010 indicated that access violation on `DX_Init()` function, I'm quire confused where I got wrong.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "D3D9.h"

#define memclear(var) \ memset(&wndClassData, 0x00, sizeof(var));

WNDCLASSEX wndClassData;

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindowProc(HWND hWnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg){
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

struct DXGlobals{
    IDirect3D9  *pD3D;
    IDirect3DDevice9 *pDevice;
};

DXGlobals gDX;
```

//I have some problems on this section

```
void DX_Init(HWND hWnd)
{
    gDX.pD3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    memclear(d3dpp);
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;

    HRESULT hr = gDX.pD3D->CreateDevice(
        D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
        D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
        hWnd,
        D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
        &d3dpp,
        &gDX.pDevice
        );
}
```

//problem end here

```
void DX_Update(){
}

void DX_Dispose(){
    gDX.pD3D->Release();
    gDX.pDevice->Release();
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,  
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, 
    int nCmdShow)
{
    //WNDCLASSEX wndClassData;

    memclear(wndClassData);

    wndClassData.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wndClassData.lpfnWndProc = MainWindowProc;
    wndClassData.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndClassData.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ARROW));
    wndClassData.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wndClassData.lpszClassName="ColourMatchingWindow";
    //memset(&wndClassData, 0x00, sizeof(wndClassData));


    ATOM wndClass = RegisterClassEx(&wndClassData);

    HWND mainWnd = CreateWindow(
        (LPCSTR)wndClass,
        "ColourMatching",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    DX_Init(mainWnd);
    MSG msg;

    for(;;){
        while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if(msg.message==WM_QUIT){
            break;
        }

        DX_Update();

    }

    DX_Dispose();

return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: For starters, try passing a valid window handle after checking the return result of your [`CreateWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx) call. Suggest you review the API. The class name you're specifying in that invoke does not match the class name you are registering. `"ColourMatchingWindow" != (LPCSTR)wndClass`. Barring that, code that *compiles* would equally help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks wrong

```
#define memclear(var) \
    memset(&wndClassData, 0x00, sizeof(var));

D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
memclear(d3dpp);
```

probably you meant the macro to look like this

```
#define memclear(var) \
    memset(&var, 0x00, sizeof(var));
```

But really you shouldn't use pointless macros. Just write the *simple and obvious* code, not the *more complex and obscure* code. Like this

```
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
memset(&d3dpp, 0x00, sizeof d3dpp);
```

Comment: macro's are evil -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-preprocessor-macros-are-evil-and-what-is-the-real-alternative-c11