# Arduino how to use namespace?

Tags: namespaces, arduino, using-directives, arduino-ide

I am using the Arduino IDE to write code and am trying to understand the namespace stuff.
My thought is, is there a way to shorten the many places (in my code) where I have things like:

```
Serial.print("a="); Serial.print(a); Serial.print(" b="); Serial.println(b);
```

to something shorter like:

```
S.print(...
```

or

```
sprint(...
```

Can it be done?

I tried using String concatenation but it is very limited and expensive. That is just adding one

```
String s;
```

to my code at the global level increased the download size by 1482 bytes. And you can't do something like:

```
Serial.print("a=" + a); Serial.println(" b=" + b);
```

because it cant handle starting a concatenation with a literal string.

Any thoughts welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arduino uses the  C++ language. [It is not considered good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives), but you could use a preprocessor macro:

`#define sprint Serial.print`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, just after my post I found #define also. It helps a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a pointer and member de-reference operator, like this:

```
HardwareSerial *my_device;

void setup()
{
  my_device->begin(9600);
  delay(100);
}

void loop()
{
  if (my_device->available())
  {
    int r = my_device->read();
    // etc.
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, the question is about keeping code short, my anwser do not apply to this case. Renato