# Constructor setting array field to null

Tags: c++, arrays, class, null

I am trying to create a constructor that sets an array field to null.
Im getting a "no viable overloaded '=' " error

```
    Horse::Horse()
    {
        string *ptr;
        ptr = NULL;
        Name[SIZE] = ptr;

    }
```

My question is what exactly is going on behind the scenes here. I thought I could create a string pointer, set it to null, then set the array to the pointer and it would make the first element of the array equal to null?

Thanks

Comment: The declaration of `Name` might just be relevant.

Comment: An array can't be set to NULL, because an array is not a pointer. But you can set the *elements* of an array to something.

Comment: Name is declares as a string array with 20 elements 

string Name[20];

Comment: That's a different type than what you're trying to assign (`string` != `string*`). Maybe just use a `std::vector` or `std::array` if you want to assign to the array?

Comment: "then set the array to the pointer" You can't do that. While an array can decay to a pointer, a pointer can't "decay" to an array.

Comment: What type is `Name`?

Comment: "it would make the first element of the array equal to null" That doesn't make sense since your array is a `std::string` array, and `std::string` can't be "null". If you mean an empty string, it's already empty. The default `std::string` constructor constructs empty strings.

Comment: Disclaimer** This is a school project. I can only assume that by "set the Name field to null" with in the constructor, means each time you create an object from the class, it starts the name array at the zero address. 

@Phantom Name is a string array with 20 elements

Comment: If name is a `char` array, you are trying to do `char = std::string*` when you do `Name[SIZE] = ptr`.

Comment: Maybe it's a C assignment and the Name field should be `char*` (i.e. C-string), not an array of `std::string`s? You can set the char pointer to null. A char array or a `std::string` can't be set to null, only pointers can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `Name[SIZE]` to point to the address of `std::string *` is meaningless.
If `Name` is a std::string array, then the array will be defaulted empty.

If your task was to set the `Name` field empty in the constructor, I'm going to assume this is a const char* instead of a std::string. This can be done using [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
Horse::Horse()
: Name{0} // Name{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} does the same thing.
{}        // empty body
```

The above will initialize all the 20 positions to 0, or NULL if you like. Just as if you declared it in the global scope.

If you are not familiar with the initializer list in constructors, you can always do this, but at an extra cost:

```
Horse::Horse() // Initialize members runs first
{
    for (int i = 0; i != SIZE; ++i) // Assign values to Name array
        Name[i] = 0;
}
```

Side note: Instead of using macros to define your values,
 a better choice is to use `const unsigned SIZE = 20;` for reasons described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives)

Comment: Okay, that worked for me. (no compiler errors but I haven't tested it yet. I have yet to build my main function.)

Answer (score 0):

I'll just go ahead and write the whole thing for you.

- If you think about what a **name** is, it's just a string, a string of characters. So `Name` should be a `std::string`. Then the constructor would look like this:

  ```
  Horse::Horse() {}
  ```

  Done. `Name` will be initialized to an empty string, i.e. `""`.
- If the assignment requires you to use C-strings (`char` arrays) instead of  `std::string`, then `Name` should be of type `char*`, if it needs to be set to `NULL`. Now the constructor would look like this:

  ```
  Horse::Horse() : Name(NULL) {}
  ```

  The `Name` field will be initialized to `NULL`, i.e. it will be a null pointer, hence it doesn't contain even an empty string.

Comment: Im not sure how the format `Horse::Horse() : Name(NULL) {}` works. Maybe I have not learned that syntax with constructors yet

Would it be incorrect to use `Name[Size] = '\0'` 

When a new instance is created does this set the address of the first element to null?

Comment: @Marty86 That's the [constructor initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) where all member variables are initialized. Doing `membervar = something` in the constructor body isn't initialization, it's assignment, and therefore doesn't work if the member is non-assignable (e.g. const, or a reference).

Comment: @Marty86 `Name[Size] = '\0'` sets the character at index `Size` to `'\0'` (i.e. the null character, which is used to terminate C-strings).

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Thanks for explaining the difference.