# Calling multiple macros from another macro in C++

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor

If I have two macros defined:

```
#define MAC1(X) {something here}
#define MAC2(X,Y) {something here}
```

and create a third one like this:

```
#define MAC3(X,Y) MAC1(X); MAC2(X,Y)
```

Can you please clarify how the `MAC3` will be evaluated if called in the code?

Comment: You can just run the preprocessor (e.g. `-E`), and see yourself. Note there's no double pass for the preprocessor, and it does only text replacement.

Comment: What isn't clear? You'll get the expansion of `MAC1` followed by the expansion of `MAC2`, just as one might expect.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, there is a smicolon at the end of MAC1, does it make any difference?

Comment: @danny: Then you'll get a semicolon in the expansion, just as one might expect.

Comment: Look into "inline functions".  Prefer functions to macros as [macros are evil.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If by the time you try to instantiate `MAC3` both `MAC1` and `MAC2` are already declared, you will get

```
{something here}; {something here}
```

In other words, `MAC1` and `MAC2` will in turn get expanded.

If, however, `MAC1` and `MAC2` are declared after you use `MAC3` (which is very unlikely), they won't get expanded.

Consider the following example:

```cpp
#define A B
#define B 5

int main()
{
    printf("%d", A);
    return 0;
};
```

It will output `5`, even though `B` is declared after `A`. What matters is that by the time you **use** `A` `B` is already declared.

Another important think to note in your example, that the `X` will get evaluated twice. For example, if you call `MAC3` like that:

```
i = 0;
MAC3(i++, 1);
```

The value of `i` at the end will be `2` (assuming both `MAC1` and `MAC2` use `X` once).

Comment: sorry there is a semicolon at the end of MAC1, i wonder does it have any significance?

Comment: No. #define's are expanded by a preprocessor that knows very little about the language itself. It just do string replacements.

Comment: actually it changes the behavior in loop statements as iv'e seen