# C++ Replacement macros in another file

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

There are posts on the forum describing how to go about making such macros, but I already know that, and I want to do it in another file, which they do not describe how to do.

Therefore, my question is - I'm going to make a program which will use a lot of replacement macros, and I therefore want them to be in another file(s), so that I have file1.cpp and every occurance of "cucumber" is replaced with "banana" using a #define macro in file2.h (I suppose it would have to be a header file?).

THE MACRO I MEAN IS: 
`#define identifier substitution_text`
which will then replace every *identifier* with *substitutuion text*.

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: Please do not use lots of replacement macros. Makes the code harder to read, harder to debug and harder to maintain

Comment: And if you *do* use macros, at least use the long-established convention of making them all upper case.

Comment: I would also recommend learning C++ from a coherent source like a book (The C++ Programming Language in particular) or a tutorial. Pulling bits and pieces from around stackoverflow, especially with a large, complex language like C++ is bound to lead you down rabbit holes that can easily be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

`#include` is what you're after.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include

But you probably are asking for the wrong tool for the job. Using macros like this is quite broadly frowned upon, [and with good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14041847/161424). If you describe what you're actually trying to do instead of how you're doing it, the answers will be a lot more helpful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I figured it out. I did it the way I thought was the way to do it and it worked. For anyone wondering, I did the #define in a header file, and then #include-d it into the origilnal.