# Make a macro: how to embed string correctly

Tags: objective-c, macros

```
#define SDNSPredicate(key,value) \
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"#key == %@",value];
```

When I use `SDNSPredicate(@"hCName",@"ccc")`, I expect `hCName == "ccc"` but it becomes `key == "ccc"`

How to make it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
#define SDNSPredicate(key,value) \
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@",key,value];
```

Comment: it will become "hCName" == "ccc" not hCName == "ccc"

Comment: And read also ->https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795

Comment: %K is a var arg substitution for a key path.This is what I am looking for.Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

> how to make it right?

Use a function. [Macros are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14041847/104790).

```
static inline NSPredicate *SDNSPredicate(NSString *key, NSString *value) {
    return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ == %@", key, value];
}
```