# How to screen the tilde in preprocessor macros?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I try write macros to define some class, but in this case i can not write destructor, because the tilde is a special character for preprocessor.

There is a example:

```
#define CLASS( cName ) \
class cName \
{ \
public: \
    cName() \
    { \
    \
    } \
    \
    ~cName() \
    { \
    \
    } \ 
};\
```

How to screen the tilde?

Comment: What compiler are you using? What error/warning message do you see?

Comment: @Carcigenicate i hope to find this way )

Comment: @owacoder C2059, MSVC++ 10

Comment: Thanks for the error number, but what exact error message(s) do you see?

Comment: The tilde is *not* a special character to the preprocessor. Your error comes from something else.

Comment: @Richard Critten i see the syntax errors C2059, C2143, but this errors are effect. They generated subsequently using the tilde

Comment: This is a bad idea. Please don't do it.

Comment: Confirming my thoughts: [it works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcc66093f068d674).

Comment: @Rob K it is not bad idea, because i do it for study only )

Comment: Study of what? How to write incomprehensible, unmaintainable code? Why don't you study something that will make your code better, not worse?

Comment: If you *need* a macro like this, I recommend taking keyboarding or typing courses.  I often cheat by using a stencil, then doing a global replace.

Comment: See [Why preprocessor macros are evil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the proper way to declare it:

```
#define MAKECLASS(name) \
class name \
{ \
public: \
    name() {} \
    ~name() {} \
};

MAKECLASS(a)
```

But I should warn you that this is in general a bad idea, why does the design of your program requires this? If it doesn't, you better not using it.

Comment: thanks, i found a problem, a one line has tab character after the slash ) Thanks you very much!