# C++ #define LPWSTR?

Tags: c++, constants, createfile, lpwstr

Ok, i have a problem in my program. I made a question about it before, but no one really understood my problem, so im trying a new approach to it this time.

If you're curious this is my problem:

> My program takes arguments in the form of `char* argv[]` , and im having trouble making a pointer to whatever is on `argv[1]` using `LPWSTR`, since it only point to `const wchar_t*` objects.

This is a new thing im trying to solve my problem (i've tried multiple things but i need to know how to do what im thinking, or if its possible)

Basicly, my idea is to `#define` some sort of function that take whatever is on `argv[1]` and defines a `const wchar_t*` with that value.

Something like this:

```
#define path       ((const wchar_t*)argv[1])
```

Im not sure that is the correct way (or even if this is possible) to do what i want to do...

If you have anny better way of solving me problem, please (please) tell me how to and help me out, i've been thinking about this so a really long time!

Explanation of my program:

> Im making a program that recieves arguments. The arguments are the name of the drives, for example "F:". It then uses the function `CreateFile` with the drive letter. If you go [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) , and see the first parameter of the function, i think you will see what i mean.... the problem is that for me to make a LPWSTR, i would need a const wchat_t* object.... I hope my question is clear this time, last time people didnt really understand what i was trying to do.

Regardless, thanks!
EDIT 1: here are solve lines of my program (this is how i have to do for it to work, without arguments) (i used a fixed value in here)

```
int main()
{

HANDLE device;

device = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\F:",    // Drive to open
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,       // Access mode
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, // Share Mode
    NULL,                   // Security Descriptor
    OPEN_EXISTING,          // How to create
    0,                      // File attributes
    NULL);  
}
```

This is with arguments (doesn't work)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

HANDLE device;

device = CreateFile(argv[1],    // Drive to open
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,       // Access mode
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, // Share Mode
    NULL,                   // Security Descriptor
    OPEN_EXISTING,          // How to create
    0,                      // File attributes
    NULL);                  // Handle to template
}
```

^ this shows what im trying to do

EDIT 2: i changed the `CreateFile` to `CreateFileA` , and this is the eroor codes it gives me (the drive D is a usb, its not a hard drive)
[image: erros]

So unless im typing the wrong way to type a path, it always gives me erros. I think ill try another way to solve the problem, or if someone knows why thoes errors are happening, please tell!

Comment: could you post some code of your program? I think it is just the first few lines of your main function.

Comment: @kennyzx sure, ill edit

Comment: maybe a macro isnt the best approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> EDIT 2: i changed the CreateFile to CreateFileA , and this is the eroor codes it gives me (the drive D is a usb, its not a hard drive)

This is a completely different question, and has nothing to do with `wchar_t`.

In your first snipped you passed `"\\\\.\\F:"` (AKA `\\.\F:` once we remove the C escaping); in all your tries from the command line you never provided this path, but respectively:

- `D` - so it tried to open a file named `D` in the current directory, and it didn't find it (error 2, aka `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`);
- `D:\` - the root directory, which cannot be opened with `CreateFile` (error 3, aka `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`),
- `D:` - the current directory on the drive D:, which again cannot be opened with `CreateFile` (error 5, aka `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`);
- `\D:` - a file named "D:" in the root of the current drive, which cannot be created given that `D:` is not a valid file name (error 123, aka `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`).

To open a drive as a device, you *must* use the `\\.\X:` path (where `X` is the drive letter); you cannot just throw whatever floats in your mind and hope that it'll work. Call your program from the command line passing `"\\.\D:"` and it'll work fine.

Of course if you want to keep it simpler for the user you can accept just the drive letter on the command line and write some code to create the string required by `CreateFile` based on it.

```
if(argc<1) {
    printf("Not enough arguments\n");
    return 1;
}
const char *drive = argv[1];
char d = drive[0];
// accept both `d` and `d:` as argument for the drive
if(!((d>='a' && d<='z') || (d>='A' && d<='Z')) ||
     (drive[1]!=0 && drive[1]!=':') ||
      drive[2]!=0) {
    printf("Invalid drive specifier: `%s`\n", drive);
    return 2;
}
char path[]="\\\\.\\X:";
path[4] = d;
// now you can use path as argument to CreateFileA
```

---

***What follows was the original answer, which is still valid but it addresses a completely different problem, unrelated to the actual problem OP is experiencing***

You cannot make `LPWSTR` point to a `char *`, especially *not* by brutally casting the pointer - casting a pointer just makes the compiler shut up, it doesn't change the fact that what you are pointing at is *not* a `wchar_t` string. If you want to pass a `char *` to a function expecting a `wchar_t *` you have to perform an actual conversion of the pointed data.

Now, you have several possible solutions:

- you can use `_wmain` and receive your command line arguments directly as wide characters;
- you can convert your local-encoding strings to UTF-16 strings by using a function such as the [MultiByteToWideChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx); this can be encapsulated in a function returning a `std::wstring`;
- you can just invoke the ANSI version of the API and let it deal with it; almost all Win32 APIs have both an ANSI and Unicode version, suffixed with A and W (`CreateFile` is just a macro that expands to `CreateFileA` or `CreateFileW` depending on the `_UNICODE` macro). So, you can use `CreateFileA` and pass it your string as-is.

The last two solutions are not great because using local-encoding strings as command line arguments precludes your program from opening files using arbitrary Unicode characters. OTOH, using `wchar_t` almost everywhere is quite a dread, since they "infect" virtually every string-processing corner of your application. The correct (IMHO) way out is to use UTF-8 everywhere, and convert on the fly when talking to the operating systems; [see here for details](http://utf8everywhere.org/#windows).

Comment: i dont understand if i do this = int _wmain(int argc, char* argv[]), wont it still save the arguments has char* ?

Comment: No, because `_wmain` has a different declaration (`int _wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])`). But the problem you have here has nothing to do with this. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: please do, i really want to understand my problem.

Comment: Updated; next time please state from the start what is the *actual* problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Dude you have no idea how much time i spend after this problem, you literally just saved my grade, can you give me anny contact info about you (name or nickname) so i can put it in my project report? (if you want only ofcoure) :-) And i wanst really understanding my problem previously, now i do, really appreciated man

Comment: That's very kind of you, Matteo Italia is my real name, you can link to [my StackOverflow profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214671/matteo-italia) if you like. :-)