# How to define a macro that expands to a conditional statement in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, macros

I want to create some context-sensitive macros. The macro

```
 #define LOG_WARNING(x) qWarning()().noquote().nospace() << x
```

works fine, it is located in file `Macros.h`. I want to define a macro, which does not print log messages when called from unit testing routine. So, I modified  like

```
#define LOG_INFO(x) if(!UNIT_TESTING) qInfo().noquote().nospace() << x
```

Since in this way the macro will depend on `UNIT_TESTING`, I provided in the same `Macros.h`

```
extern bool UNIT_TESTING;   // Whether in course of unit testing
```

However, the compilers tells

```
declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
 extern bool UNIT_TESTING; // Whether in course of unit testing
        ^
```

At the same time, if the external is declared in the file from which `Macros.h` is included, it works fine. Do I wrong something?

Comment: Are you in a `extern "C"` block ? Is `UNIT_TESTING` a macro ?

Comment: This of course is not a conditional macro. It's an unconditional macro that expands to a conditional statement.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to use a macro?  A logging class is a lot more bullet proof and you can feed that class an attribute on when to print and when not to print.

Comment: @NathanOliver well, I prefer a compile time solution,

Comment: @Jarod42 UNIT_TESTING is a simple bool, and not in extern "C"

Comment: @MSalters thanks for correcting my frazing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files) is how to share variables across source files. Nevertheless, I would highly recommend not to do so, but to implement a function  (bool IS_UNIT_TESTING() ) or class which takes care of this.  In this way you can change the implementation without changing the interface.

Moreover, [Macros are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives). They are error prone can not be debuged easily. Use inline functions or constexp instead. The compiler will optimize it to almost the very same code.