# C++ - multiple #DEFINE values cause simple arithmetics to fail

Tags: c++, long-integer, division

I am running a program, where I keep incrementing "long int" in a big loop (the value is expected up to 10^8). The "long int" in question is initialized to 0. My console print looks like this :

> errorous messages   : 400000/5000 = 800000 instances

Please notice the division is incorrect. Code printing the line above :

```
std::cout << "errorous messages   : " << total_error << "/" << GRID_SIZE << " = " << (long)((long)total_error / (long)GRID_SIZE) << " instances" << std::endl;
```

Where the variables in question are :

```
#define BLOCKS      50
#define THREADS     100
#define GRID_SIZE   BLOCKS*THREADS
```

and

```
long int total_error;  <--- incremented in a loop (never decremented, no overflow)
```

---

**What I have tried**

I have played around with recasting the division of `(long)((long)total_error / (long)GRID_SIZE)` to `(long)(total_error / GRID_SIZE)` and some others, the result is the same.

---

**Compilation Info**

```
 /opt/ohpc/pub/mpi/openmpi-gnu/1.10.6/bin/mpicxx 
-I../../common/inc -I/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include 
-I/export/home/ra2/test_cuda/test_cuda_v0_1/source_code 
-I/export/home/ra2/test_cuda/test_cuda_v0_1/source_code/Utility 
-I/export/home/ra2/test_cuda/test_cuda_v0_1/source_code/Data_objects 
-I/export/home/ra2/test_cuda/test_cuda_v0_1/source_code/cereal   
-std=c++11    -o main.o -c main.cpp
```

I am compiling with OpenMPI. There is CUDA as well, but this is main.cpp and there is no CUDA code.

---

**QUESTION**

What am I missing ? Why do I get wrong result for such a trivial operation ?

---

**Justification of the question**

- The proposed duplicate is not related to my issue, as it defines macro functions, furthermore it doesnt explain why pre-processor behaves the way it does. It merely explains the way the macro function is executed.
- My question is well explained and backed up by code producing the explained behavior. Please see how people answering this question had no issues understanding the cause of the problem.

Comment: I imagine there's a problem with your code.

Comment: Don't use macros in C++

Comment: You have `(long)((long)total_error / (long)BLOCKS*THREADS)` which is `total_error / BLOCKS * THREADS`. Don't use the preprocessor for anything unless it's the only thing that can do the job. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives

Comment: This is definitively a duplicate, but I can't find it.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Good imagination, please check the proposed answer.

Comment: @Kevin Your comment doesnt add any intelligible advice.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux If you cannot find the duplicate, then dont blame me for not finding it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `#define`s are merely textual replacement, so your

```
(long)((long)total_error / (long)GRID_SIZE)
```

is expanded to

```
(long)((long)total_error / (long)BLOCKS*THREADS)
```

And, because division (`/`), and multiplication (`*`) operators have the same precedence, entire expression is evaluated from left to right, effectively equaling:

> 400000 / 50 * 100 = 8000 * 100 = 800000

Consider wrapping calculations done in `#define`s, in parenthesis, to prevent such issues:

```
#define GRID_SIZE   (BLOCKS*THREADS)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#define GRID_SIZE   BLOCKS*THREADS
```

should be

```
#define GRID_SIZE   (BLOCKS*THREADS)
```

or better

```
const int GRID_SIZE = BLOCKS*THREADS;
```

Comment: What about `constexpr`? What about eliminating `#define BLOCKS` and `#define THREADS`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - i dont know constexpr - does it help here?