# What is the reason for a define clashing with a typedef enum in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have some code which has some code that looks like this one here (I simplified it, of course)

```
#define ERROR 0

namespace lib{
    class Logger{
         public:
             typedef enum {ERROR = 1} LogLevel;
    };
}
```

When compiling in visual studio I get the error: `syntax error: 'constant'`. It is clear that the problem is that I am re-using the word ERROR for the define and the typedef enum.

Does anyone know the logic of the define influencing some variable name that is is fact included inside a namespace and a class. I mean, how can `ERROR` be confused with `lib::Logger::ERROR` since my guess is that they have completely different scopes.

Comment: It's a macro. That means that every place where the compiler sees `ERROR` it replaces it with `0`. And, no, it doesn't "compile with g++". Something else might compile, but this code won't.

Comment: The main reason is that you've adopted a Java/Python convention, namely uppercase for constants, in C++ where it Does Not Make Sense.

Comment: **−1** For posting code that is **not the real code**.

Comment: You are right @Pete Becker,  it does not compile in g++, I just realised the define actually comes from a windows default include wingdi.h that does not exists when compiling with g++. This the preprocessor might even replace variable names, I guess. Thanks.

Comment: `namesspace` O RLY? Post the actual code you're using, which is presumably not that, or you'd be getting a different problem.

Comment: Hi! Just ran into exactly this problem where a colleague used ALL CAPS for enum values... Some never learn, and some have never learnt.

Answer (score 7):

Preprocessor `#define` substitution is one of the first things to happen when you compile your code. These substitutions are made textually and ignore c++ syntax. Your code is equivalent to :

```
namespace lib{
    class Logger{
         public:
             typedef enum {0 = 1} LogLevel;
    };
}
```

It's obvious that, after the substitution of `ERROR` with `0` your `enum` definition is ill-formed.

Using preprocessor marcos is generally seen as a bad idea if any other mechanism can do the same job instead. This question illustrates one of the many risks associated with using them. See the question [Why are preprocessor macros evil and what are the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Probably worth throwing in that macros are considered evil in general usage with a number of levels of hell reserved for their misuse;  but have an upvote for being able to understand that namesspace was a typo.