# Override compiler macro in base class

Tags: c++, directive

In my base class B.cpp I have a macro

```
#define PRODUCT "MY PRODUCT B"
```

which is used in numerous outputs etc.  I now derive class D from B, and would to replace the macro with

```
#define PRODUCT "NEW PRODUCT D"
```

Is there a way to do this?  Does it just come down to compilation order (random)?

Comment: That's called a macro... Avoid them in C++.

Comment: Why should macro's be avoided in C++ ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives

Answer (score 2):

A variation on Edgar's answer, which may be more suitable or less suitable depending on what you are trying to accomplish:

```
class Base {
private:
  virtual const std::string Product() const {
    return "MY PRODUCT B";
  }
};

class Derived {
private:
  virtual const std::string Product() const override {
    return "MY PRODUCT D";
  }
};
```

If you this answer better than Edgar's, I'd rather you give Edgar credit for answering the question.

Comment: Interesting idea.  Why should the method in the Derived also be virtual?

Comment: @TSG It is virtual because the language spec says so. But it isn't necessary to write `virtual` in the derived class. It is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think macros are reliable way to achieve this.

I suggest using static members instead:

```
class Base {
private:
    static const std::string PRODUCT;
};

const std::string Base::PRODUCT = "MY PRODUCT B";

class Derived {
private:
    static const std::string PRODUCT;
};

const std::string Derived::PRODUCT = "MY PRODUCT D";
```

Now you are able to use `PRODUCT` in both `Base` and `Derived` classes.

Answer (score 0):

> Why should macro's be avoided in C++

Macros cross scope boundaries, as your example description loudly reports.

> Does it just come down to compilation order (random)?

I never have random compilation order, but I use makefiles where the dependencies control the order.  Note, your builds should also be repeatable.

> Is there a way to do this? [redefine the macro to change only where desired]

Possibly ... can you reliably "#undef PRODUCT" just before the defining the second "#define PRODUCT ..."  AND not have the second definition seen by code in which you want the first definition.

Consider:

create two zones in your code ...

```
#define PRODUCT "MY PRODUCT B"

// zone a

#undef  PRODUCT


#define PRODUCT "NEW PRODUCT D"

// zone b

#undef  PRODUCT
```

Put code corresponding to and dependent on the definition in to the appropriate zone.

---

One solution:

I had macro surprises with a 3rd party code containing macros which messed with my symbol names. Its as if they had defined macros with commonly used meaning like: open, close, read, write, etc.  My method  "Foo_t::open()" etc. would be stomped on.

I solved this issue (perhaps clumsily) by

- including the 3rd party header in one cpp ONLY, such that the 'macros' I did use were only invoked  by the code I wrote to use it, not in any other compilation unit.  (i.e. I controlled where I introduced the macros via #include.)

and

- adding a few somewhat 'higher-level' c++ methods below that include, this is the code which made use of the macros.  These 'higher-level' c++ methods were declared in hpp, and defined in the cpp.  Other code used these methods ... I suppose in some sense I 'wrapped' the macros.