# How to make C++ macro from std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, macros

I have this in my c++ code:

```
std::vector<WCHAR> sText(4096);
```

I want to simplify it into a macro  so I'm not always typing `std::vector<WCHAR>` every time. I can't figure out how to shorthand this into a macro. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: `using your_new_name_here = std::vector<WCHAR>;`

Comment: For a variable named `sText` and which contains characters, wouldn't a *string* be better? As in `std::wstring sText;`?

Comment: And a general tip for creating shorthand names of types: Don't. They tend to make the code *harder* to read and understand. Either you need to make the name descriptive enough that it's often longer than the original type it's supposed to replace, or you need to add some semantic meaning to the alias.

Comment: if I use `using your_new_name_here = std::vector<WCHAR>`, how do I tell it what size to use?

Comment: It's just another name. Use it the same.

Comment: Some additional reading on macros focusing on why and where you should avoid them: [Why are preprocessor macros evil and what are the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives)

Comment: This name is tiny. Just type it. It's easy.