# C Program Result Explanation

Tags: c++

Dear(s) I have the following code of C that give me the answer = 11 correct but I cannot pick the point over here. Kindly explain if any have the key.

## include

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    #define square(x) x*x
    cout<<square(3+2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your code is `c++` and you need to understand operator precedence

Comment: you can refer [Why are preprocessor macros evil and what are the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives)

Comment: This is a good case to use an *inline* function.

Comment: To see why macros are evil, try this: `square("board")`.

Answer (score 5):

`square(3+2)` expands into `3+2*3+2`, which evaluates as `3 + (2 * 3) + 2`.

`#define square(x) ((x) * (x))` should do what you want.

(The inner parentheses solve the problem you presented, the outer parentheses solve the problem you haven't found yet :P In fact, make it `SQUARE`, just in case, for yet another issue. Read TruthSeeker's link for details.)

Comment: [`std::pow(3+2, 2)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) also does what he wants. Always use the standard stuff.

Comment: @nada: `std::pow` has no `int` version, and does a lot more processing than `x * x`.

Comment: You're suggesting premature optimization and use of macros over code readability and using the C++ standard library?

Comment: @nada `x * x` _is_ standard stuff. And I don't particularly consider `pow(x, 2)` more readable. _shrug_ Finally, `pow(x, 2)` does not answer this particular question (why the result is 11). Also, I don't see it as a micro-optimisation when it changes literally only one line. If you argued for an inline function over macro, all good; but using `pow` for integral square is not avoiding premature optimisation, but being a wanton wastrel.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating your pov _wink_. Inline function sounds good. After all, macros are the reason why OP had to come here in the first place.