# Macro for tuple parameters

Tags: c++

Is it possible to make macro that expand tuple parameters depending on N? Like we need tuple with "3 int". So we just write m(3) which becomes "int, int, int"

```
const int k = 3;
#define m(N) int, int, int   //how to write int, int, int here in cycle?
typedef std::tuple<m(k)> new_type;
```

Is there maybe another way to do this?

Comment: Macros are considered bad practice for [some reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives). If your tuple only consists of `int`, why not simply use a `std::array<int, k>`?

Comment: You can indeed make MACRO for that, but you will be limited by hard-coded limit. template seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define function which returns a tuple with given `T` type repetead `N` times:

```
template<class T, size_t ... indices>
auto helper(std::index_sequence<indices...>) {
    return std::tuple_cat( (indices,std::tuple<T>())... );
}

template<class T, size_t N>
auto genTuple() {
    return helper<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

Then, define alias template taking type and number of reps:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
using Tuple = decltype(genTuple<T,N>());
```

by decltype you get return type of function - your desired tuple.

Usage:

```
Tuple<int,3> t;
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/QyM-zv)

Answer (score 1):

Whereas you can do some REPEAT MACRO (which would forward to REPEAT_3, REPEAT_2 and REPEAT_1) and would have some hard coded limit,

you might use instead template for the generation, for example:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t> using always_t = T;

template <typename T, typename Seq> struct gen_tuple_helper;

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
struct gen_tuple_helper
{
    using type = std::tuple<always_t<T, Is>...>;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using gen_tuple_t = typename gen_tuple_helper<T, std::make_index_sequence<T>>::type;


static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::tuple<int, int, int>, gen_tuple_t<int, 3>>);
```

Note: As noted in comment homogeneous `std::tuple` might be replaced by `std::array` which seems simpler to manipulate.