# Operator to convert to string

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Why does the code snippet 1 works but NOT code snippet 2

Code Snippet 1:

```
#define mkstr(x) #x

int main(void)
{
    printf(mkstr(abc));

    return (0);
}
```

Code Snippet 2:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf(#abc);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: because the # is macro synatx and you don't have a macro in snippet 2

Comment: Please stop using macros! We have 2020 and you simply should stop coding like the 70s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands starting with the `#` symbol are called Macros in C and C++. Macros are blocks of code that are named and referenced with that name.

There are 2 popular types of macros - the *Object-like* and the *function-like*. The one you're using is the *function-like* macro.

The Preprocessor is responsible for replacing macro calls with the actual object/function calls.

The statement in Snippet 1

```cpp
#define mkstr(x) #x
```

The above macro uses a special feature called the *stringizing*. The `#` before the `x` specifies that the input parameter should be treated as is, ie. converted to a string constant, thereby returning a string equivalent of what is passed.

On the contrary, when you call the below code in Snippet 2

```cpp
printf(#abc);
```

doesn't mean anything. It's a compiler error as `#`s are not allowed in the middle or end of a statement (please not that `#` is allowed to be part of string such as "#1", or when used as a character literal as `'#'`). And thus any statement that starts with `#` becomes a macro.

**Caution:** Use of macros is discouraged. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14041847) answer on StackOverflow on why not to use them.

Refer the below resources to learn more about macros

- [Macro (The C Preprocessor) - GNU GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html)
- [C Preprocessors and Macros - Programiz](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-preprocessor-macros)

Answer (score 2):

The first snippet works because it has a function-like macro defined in which you put anything, the value is correctly assigned as a constant.

OTOH, the second one has a syntactic error because the compiler doesn't expects that parameter passed in `printf()`. Thus, the `#` is meaningless there.

Comment: You could leave the C++ tag, but I can't argue with your edit, C and C++ are different languages and the separation is encouraged, like @klutt stated int the accepted answer.

Comment: @anastaciu the question is explicitly asked for C. That's why I had removed C++ tag and nothing. If you see something irrelevant in the edit, then you can take it back. No problem at all.

Comment: No, I think it's ok.