# C++ Use alias for 'typename'?

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef

I'm working with templates, and it's getting kinda tedious to write "typename" multiple times.
Is it possible to assign an alias to it? I understand that the below doesn't work, is there any other ways?

```cpp
typedef typename tn;
```

Comment: It would be possible with MACRO...

Comment: @Jarod42 Even though I'm not very fond of macros, that'll have to do for now

Comment: If this is a situation where someone will be reading your code ever I would advise against  that. You may be able to create some shortcut key in your IDE instead to avoid the extra typing.

Comment: Aliases are for types. `typename` is a keyword.

Comment: The reason it is possible with macro is that the preprocessor will put `typename` everywhere `tn` occurred. I also recommend against. I also don't recommend using macros at all, some of the reasons can be found [Why are macros evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives)

Comment: @TonyTannous So is there any other alternative ways for aliasing keywords besides a preprocessor macro? Would be pretty useful

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You can also write `class` instead of `typename`

Comment: Bummer. I guess I'm gonna have to accept the macro answer by @Jarod42

Comment: Why do this? Anybody reading your code will have an extremely hard time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use MACRO

```
#define tn typename
```