# C++20: generate type from given variadic types

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, c++20, variadic-macros, fold-expression

Lets say, I have a variadic type list which can grow
e.g.

```
#define MY_TYPES  void, float, int, vector<long>, .....
```

I am looking for way to generate these type definition at compile time in c++17/20 in generic way, e.g.

```
#define to_tuple(MY_TYPES) ==> std::tuple<future<void>, future<float>, future<int>....>
using tupleType = decltype(to_tuple<ALL_TYPES>); // this can be then used in struct as a member.

struct foo {
   ...
   ...
   tupleType tups;
}
```

or, alternatively if this can be done using template metaprogramming ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please [avoid macros like a fire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14041847/1387438). There is some cases there is no choice, but they are quite rare and it is not your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <typename ...P>
using tuple_of_futures_t = std::tuple<std::future<P>...>;

using X = tuple_of_futures_t<void, float, int, std::vector<long>>;
```