# How to decompose a pointer-to-member in C++ (get class and member types)?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

I have this scenario:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class SomeClass
{
public:
    int _int;
};

#define DO_SOME_STUFF(ptr) std::cout << /* Print the typeid().hash_code() of the type which ptr is poiting to (int) */;

int main()
{
    int SomeClass::* ptr_to_int_member = &SomeClass::_int;
    DO_SOME_STUFF(ptr_to_int_member)
}
```

I want to know which type is `ptr` pointing at (which is currently `int`).
Knowing which class owns that `int` is also useful (which is currently `SomeClass`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with a "`template` trick":

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct PointerToMemberDecomposer {};

template<typename T, typename P>
struct PointerToMemberDecomposer<P T::*>
{
    using ClassType = T;
    using MemberType = P;
};
```

And change your code to:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct PointerToMemberDecomposer {};

template<typename T, typename P>
struct PointerToMemberDecomposer<P T::*>
{
    using ClassType = T;
    using MemberType = P;
};

class SomeClass
{
public:
    int _int;
};

#define DO_SOME_STUFF(ptr) std::cout << typeid(PointerToMemberDecomposer<decltype(ptr)>::MemberType).hash_code();

int main()
{
    int SomeClass::* ptr_to_int_member = &SomeClass::_int;
    DO_SOME_STUFF(ptr_to_int_member)
}
```

Defining a couple of templated aliases can make the code a little bit cleaner:

```cpp
#define GET_POINTER_TO_MEMBER_CLASS_TYPE(ptr) PointerToMemberDecomposer<decltype(ptr)>::ClassType
#define GET_POINTER_TO_MEMBER_MEMBER_TYPE(ptr) PointerToMemberDecomposer<decltype(ptr)>::MemberType
```

So you can change `DO_SOME_STUFF` to:

```cpp
#define DO_SOME_STUFF(ptr) std::cout << typeid(GET_POINTER_TO_MEMBER_MEMBER_TYPE(ptr)).hash_code();
```

---

### Explanation

This technique is called `Partial template specialization`.
The second definition of `PointerToMemberDecomposer` will be used when a `pointer-to-member` type is passed as template argument; And will catch new `T` and `P` `typename`s. using those new `typename`s; It will define two type aliases (`ClassType` and `MemberType`) so `T` and `P` can be used outside of the `PointerToMemberDecomposer` struct.

When using `PointerToMemberDecomposer`; you should use [decltype](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) operator which acts like `type` in Python or `typeof` in C#. `decltype(x)` passes the type of `x` instead of `x` itself.

---

### Update

As `463035818_is_not_a_number` have mentioned; macros can be replaced with `templated aliases`

```cpp
template <typename T>
using ClassTypeFromPtrToMember_t = typename PointerToMemberDecomposer<T>::ClassType;

template <typename T>
using MemberTypeFromPtrToMember_t = typename PointerToMemberDecomposer<T>::MemberType;
```

But you should still use `decltype` while `DO_SOME_STUFF` is a macro instead of a templated function and we cant access `ptr`'s type directly (see [463035818_is_not_a_number's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68252898/11814750) for templated function version of `DO_SOME_STUFF`):

```cpp
#define DO_SOME_STUFF(ptr) std::cout << typeid(MemberTypeFromPtrToMember_t<decltype(ptr)>).hash_code();
```

In this case; `DO_SOME_STUFF` can be converted to a templated function. But you might want to for example fill a non capturing lambda with macro arguments; which requires `DO_SOME_STUFF` to be a macro.

Also, you might want to change `ClassType` and `MemberType` to `type` and create two separated `struct`s (or `class`es) for retrieving those type aliases; If you want `PointerToMemberDecomposer` to look like C++'s standard library.

For more details; see [463035818_is_not_a_number's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68252898/11814750)

Comment: Pretty nice answer until the *"macros to make it cleaner"*. No. If you want to make it cleaner you might use a type alias.

Comment: fwiw, it is common to name the memebr alias just `type`. You could have two seperate traits, `Member<decltype(ptr)>::type` and `Class<decltype(ptr)>::type`.

Comment: agree with spectras, nice answer, only the macros are a little off. For readability you can `using type = PointerToMemberDecomposer<decltype(ptr)>::Class`. Your macro isnt much less to type than the original and has the downsides of being a macro (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives).

Comment: minotr nitpick: "It declares the type of the expression.." isnt quite right. Rather ["Inspects the declared type of an entity or the type and value category of an expression. "](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).

Comment: You could indeed make a function template out of it. `template<A> void DO_SOME_STUFF(A& a) { std::cout << /* Something with PointerToMemberDecomposer<A> */}` - no need to use `decltype` even.

Comment: I liked the answer much better before the Update. I don't understand what you mean with "you might want to for example fill a non capturing lambda with macro arguments;". Nowadays necessary uses of macros are extremely rare. Since C++20 introduced `std::source_location` I am actually not aware of any valid use case, unless we are talking about large scale code generation.

Comment: also it doesnt fit the question-answer dialoge well, the update is a reply to my answer rather than to your question. Also, frankly, I think you didnt quite get the point of replacing the macro. The template alias is merely to avoid the necessity of `typename` when using the trait, it is not essential to replace the macro

Comment: note that it is completely fine to have more than one complementary answers. Not everything must be included in a single answer.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number In the real code; I use a macro to create a property-getter lambda. this macro takes in a `pointer-to-member` and puts it into the lambda function. If I use a template function; the lambda should capture that `pointer-to-member` and it could no longer be stored as a `function-pointer`. If you have a solution for that (such as taking the `pointer-to-member` as another template); please help. because I am also not a fan of macros.

Comment: @OverShifted if you post it as question I am sure we can find a solution without macros.

Answer (score 2):

Just summarizing comments to some otherwise great answer...

Member aliases are commonly named just `type`. Macros are better avoided ([Why are preprocessor macros evil and what are the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives)) and for less verbosity on the caller you can use a function template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T>
struct TypeFromPtrToMember; // needs no definition

template<typename T, typename P>
struct TypeFromPtrToMember<P T::*>
{
    using type = T;
};

class SomeClass
{
public:
    int _int;
};

template <typename T>
void do_some_stuff(T t){
    std::cout << typeid(typename TypeFromPtrToMember<T>::type).hash_code();;
}

int main()
{
    int SomeClass::* ptr_to_int_member = &SomeClass::_int;
    do_some_stuff(ptr_to_int_member);
}
```

Naming the member alias `type` is [so common](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) that I would do it even if you then need two traits. The other trait is basically the same just with `using type = P;`.

In the above, there is still the little annoyance of having to write `typename` when using the trait (because `TypeFromPtrToMember<T>::type` is a [dependent name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name)). Since C++11 we can use a [template alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) to help with that. Template aliases cannot be partially specialized, but we already have the trait and just need to forward to that:

```
template <typename T>
using TypeFromPtrToMember_t = typename TypeFromPtrToMember<T>::type;
```

Such that `do_some_stuff` can be:

```
template <typename T>
void do_some_stuff(T t){
    std::cout << typeid(TypeFromPtrToMember_t<T>).hash_code();;
}
```

I hope you agree that now no macros are needed anymore.