# C++ #define directive

Tags: c++, operation

There is the next code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define F(x) (2*x*x)
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    int res = F(a + b);
}
```

The res value is 6, but why is it?

Comment: Try `#define F(x) (2*(x)*(x))` and see what you get.

Comment: Macros are simple text replacement. Your macro gets expanded to `(2*a+b*a+b)`

Comment: [Macros are evil!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14041453/10077)

Answer (score 3):

Macros are used to replace the text. This is what ht code is doing:

```
2*x*x
```

replacing x with (a+b)
`2*a+b*a+b`

a = 1
b = 2

Answer is 6

Answer (score 0):

The `#define` directive simply replace the parameter in the macro. So in your code:

`F(a + b)` turns into `2*a + b*a + b` which is `2*1+2*1+2` that is equal to 6.

I suggest to use inline functions for this matter, but if you really want to use a macro (which is highly unrecommended for cases like these for many reasons) surround each parameter with brackets.

Example: `#define F(x) (2*(x)*(x))`