# How to expand a recursive macro via __VA_OPT__ in a nested context

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, c++20, variadic-macros

I have read [this article](https://www.scs.stanford.edu/%7Edm/blog/va-opt.html), which illustrates how the `__VA_OPT__` function macro can be used to recursively expand a macro. I would like to implement something similar, with the difference being that the macro is expanded in a nested context.

The input:

```cpp
NEST_RECURSIVE(A, B, C)
```

should produce (order is irrelevant):

```cpp
((( | C) | B) | A)
```

My approach is slightly generalized from the article:

```cpp
#define PARENS ()

#define EXPAND(...) EXPAND4(EXPAND4(EXPAND4(EXPAND4(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND4(...) EXPAND3(EXPAND3(EXPAND3(EXPAND3(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND3(...) EXPAND2(EXPAND2(EXPAND2(EXPAND2(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND2(...) EXPAND1(EXPAND1(EXPAND1(EXPAND1(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND1(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define FOR_EACH_R(func, ...) __VA_OPT__(EXPAND(FOR_EACH_HELPER_R(func, __VA_ARGS__)))
#define FOR_EACH_HELPER_R(func, sub, ...) func(__VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R PARENS (func, __VA_ARGS__)), sub)
#define FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R() FOR_EACH_HELPER_R

#define MY_FUNC(nested, var) (nested | var)
#define NEST_RECURSIVE(...) FOR_EACH_R(MY_FUNC, __VA_ARGS__)
```

The current code produces the following output:

```cpp
(FOR_EACH_HELPER_R (MY_FUNC, B, C) | A)
```

As can be seen the expansion does not occur past the first level.

I imagine I'd have to `EXPAND` somewhere else, however, I cannot figure out where.

It's entirely possible that what I'm looking to do is impossible, however, the pre-C++20 method of recursive macro expansion (utilizing `PP_NARG`) does work with nesting, so I'd hope the new, cleaner, approach works with it as well!

Comment: Why put all that effort into MACRO's (specifically using C++20) when there are so many (meta) template options available? So my question back is WHAT are you trying to solve there might be better ways then macros. Read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives#:~:text=when%20defining%20macros%20for%20magic,functions%20and%20they%20do%20not.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the output you want, and what should the macro "signature" look like?

Comment: @PepijnKramer of course you're right, but in this case I don't have much choice, since I'm using this to extend a testing framework which itself relies on macros, so nothing else will be an option, sadly.

Comment: @ViralTaco_ Input: `NEST_RECURSIVE(A, B, C)`, Output: `((( | C) | B) | A)`, Signature: `NEST_RECURSIVE(...)`

Comment: @Salvage Lord, have mercy. That seems very complex. I'm not sure that I even want to become that good at engineering macros.  Have you considered a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) instead?

Comment: @Salvage Meh, that's suboptimal. Well I lost all my macro skills a long time ago so can't help you. Hope someone else can

Comment: @ViralTaco_ I can't use anythingbesides macros because I'm building this as an extension to an existing framework which relies on macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your basic `FOR_EACH_R` is correct, what's causing the problem is the call to `func` within your `FOR_EACH_HELPER_R` macro.

You can verify this by temporarely removing it:

```cpp
/* ... */
#define FOR_EACH_HELPER_R(func, sub, ...) (__VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R PARENS (func, __VA_ARGS__)), sub)
/* ... */

NEST_RECURSIVE(A, B, C)
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/PKrP7xsMr)

would result in:

```
(((, C), B), A)
```

---

##### 1. How Macro Evaluation works

Macro Evaluation is not very intuitive, so i'll quickly explain the 2 concepts that are important to this answer:

###### 1.1 function-like macro evaluation order

Example:

```cpp
#define FOO() 1
#define BAR() 2
#define BAZ(A, B) MIAU(A, B)
#define MIAU(A, B) B A

BAZ(FOO(), BAR())
```

When the preprocessor sees the call to `BAZ()` the following things will happen:

- 1. The arguments are fully evaluated:

  - `FOO()` -> 1
  - `BAR()` -> 2
- 2. The evaluated values are substituted into the macro body:

  - `BAZ(1, 2)` -> `MIAU(1, 2)`
- 3. The macro body is fully evaluated **again**

  - `MIAU(1, 2)` -> `2 1`

So arguments can be potentially evaluated twice - once before they are substituted into the macro body and then again when the body is evaluated.

This is also why you can pass macros as arguments to other macros, e.g.:

```cpp
#define FOO(fn) fn()
#define BAR() 12

FOO(BAR)
```

Here the following things would happen:

- 1. Preprocessor fully evaluates arguments:
     `BAR` does name a macro, but it's not a macro call. So the preprocessor will not evaluate it and treats it as text: `BAR`
- 2. Substitution into the macro body:
     `FOO(BAR)` -> `BAR()`
- 3. Evaluation of the body:
     `BAR()` -> `12`

Your `EXPAND` macro also uses this to repeatedly force evaluation of an expression.

###### 1.2 You can't call a macro from itself

e.g.:

```cpp
#define FOO 1 + FOO

FOO

#define BAR 1 + BAZ
#define BAZ BAR

BAR
```

- `FOO` would result in `1 + FOO`
- `BAR` would result in `1 + BAR`

Essentially while the preprocessor is evaluating a given macro, e.g. `BAR`, any occurance of `BAR` within it (or in one of the macros it calls) will be marked as **don't try to evaluate this - EVER**.

So basically once a macro sees it's own name it's game over.

---

##### 2. Why your example doesn't work

Let's walk through the evaluation of your `FOR_EACH_R` macro:
(i'll leave out the `EXPAND` macros for simplicity)

1. First `EXPAND` round

- first we start with `FOR_EACH_HELPER_R(MY_FUNC, A, B, C)`
- substition into body: `MY_FUNC(FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R PARENS (MY_FUNC, B, C), A)`
- then evaluate the body

  - the preprocessor sees the call to `MY_FUNC`, so both arguments will be evaluated:

    - `FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R PARENS (MY_FUNC, B, C)` becomes `FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R () (MY_FUNC, B, C)` (not evaluated further due to `FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R` not being a direct call)
    - `A` -> `A`
- substitute into `MY_FUNC` body:
  `MY_FUNC((FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R () (MY_FUNC, B, C)), A)`
  ->
  `(FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R () (MY_FUNC, B, C) | A)`
- evaluate body:
  `(FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R () (MY_FUNC, B, C) | A)`
  ->
  `(FOR_EACH_HELPER_R (MY_FUNC, B, C) | A)`
  ->
  preprocessor detects recursion (we are in `MY_FUNC` which was called by `FOR_EACH_HELPER_R` and we are trying to call `FOR_EACH_HELPER_R` again here)
  so the `FOR_EACH_HELPER_R` will be marked as **don't try to evaluate this**
  additionally the `MY_FUNC` parameter will also be marked (since we're in `MY_FUNC`)

2. Every `EXPAND` round after that

- preprocessor tries to evaluate the current expression:
  `(FOR_EACH_HELPER_R (MY_FUNC, B, C) | A)`
  but `FOR_EACH_HELPER_R` is marked as **don't try to evaluate this**, so the call is ignored and nothing gets replaced.

-> You end up with `(FOR_EACH_HELPER_R (MY_FUNC, B, C) | A)` as output

---

##### 3. How to fix it

The big problem is that you pass `FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R(...)` as an argument to your `func`, which will evaluate that part twice (once as argument, once in the body), so the preprocessor sees the recursive call and stops.

You can partially fix it by delaying the `FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R` by another evaluation cycle, e.g.:

```cpp
/* ... */
#define FOR_EACH_HELPER_R(func, sub, ...) func (__VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R PARENS (func, __VA_ARGS__)), sub)
#define FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R() FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R_IMPL PARENS
#define FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R_IMPL() FOR_EACH_HELPER_R
/* ... */
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/oGPexbKf3)

This would result in:

```
(MY_FUNC (MY_FUNC (, C), B) | A)
```

Now the loop got fully expanded, however there's still a recursion problem with `MY_FUNC`.
The underlying issue here is that one of the parameters to `MY_FUNC` will contain `MY_FUNC`, e.g.:

```cpp
MY_FUNC((FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R PARENS (MY_FUNC, B, C)), A)
```

so once the preprocessor substitutes `MY_FUNC` into `MY_FUNC` that token will be immediatly marked as **don't ever try to evaluate that again**.
So the `MY_FUNC` chain gets stuck after the first call.

It would be a lot easier if you wouldn't need recursive calls, e.g.:

```cpp
/* ... */
#define FOR_EACH_HELPER_R(func, sub, ...) __VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R PARENS (func, __VA_ARGS__)), func(sub)
/* ... */
#define MY_FUNC(var) (var)
/* ... */
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/8EKfdhPP5)

would work without problems (result would be `, (C), (B), (A)`)

If you absolutely need the recursive calls, then there is only one way:

You need to make sure that `MY_FUNC` never gets to see `FOR_EACH_HELPER_R` & `MY_FUNC`.
But given that each invocation of `MY_FUNC` needs the result of the previous invocation, your only option is to build the macro in such a way that all the `MY_FUNC` calls are evaluated at once.

e.g. you need to build `FOR_EACH_HELPER_R` in such a way that eventually you're left with:

```cpp
MY_FUNC(MY_FUNC(MY_FUNC(, C), B), A)
```

so that the recursive calls will be evaluated correctly.

The easiest way to ensure this is to use the same delay trick you use for `FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R`, e.g. with a set of macros like this:

```cpp
#define DELAY6(...) DELAY6_IMPL PARENS __VA_OPT__((__VA_ARGS__))
#define DELAY5(...) DELAY5_IMPL PARENS __VA_OPT__((__VA_ARGS__))
#define DELAY4(...) DELAY4_IMPL PARENS __VA_OPT__((__VA_ARGS__))
#define DELAY3(...) DELAY3_IMPL PARENS __VA_OPT__((__VA_ARGS__))
#define DELAY2(...) DELAY2_IMPL PARENS __VA_OPT__((__VA_ARGS__))
#define DELAY1(...) DELAY1_IMPL PARENS __VA_OPT__((__VA_ARGS__))
#define DELAY0(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define DELAY6_IMPL() DELAY5
#define DELAY5_IMPL() DELAY4
#define DELAY4_IMPL() DELAY3
#define DELAY3_IMPL() DELAY2
#define DELAY2_IMPL() DELAY1
#define DELAY1_IMPL() DELAY0
```

So `DELAY6` will delay it for 6 evaluations, `DELAY5` for 5, etc...

Then you can use it to delay the call to `MY_FUNC`, e.g.:

```cpp
#define FOR_EACH_R(func, ...) __VA_OPT__(EXPAND(FOR_EACH_HELPER_R(func, DELAY6, __VA_ARGS__)))
#define FOR_EACH_HELPER_R(func, del, sub, ...) del(func) (__VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R PARENS (func, del(), __VA_ARGS__)), sub)
```

notice that we're passing `del()`, not `del` to the next iteration of `FOR_EACH_HELPER_R`, this will effectively result in the next lower `DELAY*` function being passed (so that all the delays resolve in a single evaluation)

With `NEST_RECURSIVE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G)` this would evaluate as following:

```
DELAY5_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (DELAY5_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R () (MY_FUNC, DELAY5_IMPL () , C, D, E, F, G), B), A)
->
DELAY4_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (DELAY4_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (DELAY4_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R () (MY_FUNC, DELAY4_IMPL () , D, E, F, G), C), B), A)
->
DELAY3_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (DELAY3_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (DELAY3_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (DELAY3_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R () (MY_FUNC, DELAY3_IMPL () , E, F, G), D), C), B), A)
->
DELAY2_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (DELAY2_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (DELAY2_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (DELAY2_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (DELAY2_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R () (MY_FUNC, DELAY2_IMPL () , F, G), E), D), C), B), A)
->
DELAY1_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (DELAY1_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (DELAY1_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (DELAY1_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (DELAY1_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (DELAY1_IMPL () (MY_FUNC) (FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R () (MY_FUNC, DELAY1_IMPL () , G), F), E), D), C), B), A)
->
((((((( | G) | F) | E) | D) | C) | B) | A)
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/q17P4Pjd5)

Notice that `MY_FUNC` didn't get called until the last evaluation round - this essentially ensures that all MY_FUNC calls are evaluated at once and we don't get any problems with recursive macro calls.

You'll have to define a lot of `DELAY_` macros though for this to work (1 more delay macro for each additional parameter to `FOR_EACH_R`)

Full code example: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/q17P4Pjd5)

```cpp
#define PARENS ()

#define EXPAND(...) EXPAND4(EXPAND4(EXPAND4(EXPAND4(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND4(...) EXPAND3(EXPAND3(EXPAND3(EXPAND3(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND3(...) EXPAND2(EXPAND2(EXPAND2(EXPAND2(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND2(...) EXPAND1(EXPAND1(EXPAND1(EXPAND1(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND1(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define DELAY6(...) DELAY6_IMPL PARENS __VA_OPT__((__VA_ARGS__))
#define DELAY5(...) DELAY5_IMPL PARENS __VA_OPT__((__VA_ARGS__))
#define DELAY4(...) DELAY4_IMPL PARENS __VA_OPT__((__VA_ARGS__))
#define DELAY3(...) DELAY3_IMPL PARENS __VA_OPT__((__VA_ARGS__))
#define DELAY2(...) DELAY2_IMPL PARENS __VA_OPT__((__VA_ARGS__))
#define DELAY1(...) DELAY1_IMPL PARENS __VA_OPT__((__VA_ARGS__))
#define DELAY0(...) __VA_ARGS__



#define DELAY6_IMPL() DELAY5
#define DELAY5_IMPL() DELAY4
#define DELAY4_IMPL() DELAY3
#define DELAY3_IMPL() DELAY2
#define DELAY2_IMPL() DELAY1
#define DELAY1_IMPL() DELAY0


#define FOR_EACH_R(func, ...) __VA_OPT__(EXPAND(FOR_EACH_HELPER_R(func, DELAY6, __VA_ARGS__)))
#define FOR_EACH_HELPER_R(func, del, sub, ...) del(func) (__VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R PARENS (func, del(), __VA_ARGS__)), sub)
#define FOR_EACH_AGAIN_R() FOR_EACH_HELPER_R

#define MY_FUNC(nested, var) (nested | var)
#define NEST_RECURSIVE(...) FOR_EACH_R(MY_FUNC, __VA_ARGS__)

NEST_RECURSIVE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G)
```

---

##### 4. Potentially better approaches

###### 4.1 Simple macro chain

The above solution requires a very good understanding of how macros are evaluated to understand what's happending. You could also choose an easier approach by just defining a bunch of macros, like [boost does for example](https://github.com/boostorg/preprocessor/blob/develop/include/boost/preprocessor/seq/fold_left.hpp)

e.g.:

```cpp
#define FOR_EACH_ERROR()

#define FOR_EACH_R(fn, ...) __VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_0(fn, __VA_ARGS__))
#define FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_0(fn, el, ...) fn(__VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_1(fn, __VA_ARGS__)), el)
#define FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_1(fn, el, ...) fn(__VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_2(fn, __VA_ARGS__)), el)
#define FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_2(fn, el, ...) fn(__VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_3(fn, __VA_ARGS__)), el)
#define FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_3(fn, el, ...) fn(__VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_4(fn, __VA_ARGS__)), el)
#define FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_4(fn, el, ...) fn(__VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_5(fn, __VA_ARGS__)), el)
#define FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_5(fn, el, ...) fn(__VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_6(fn, __VA_ARGS__)), el)
#define FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_6(fn, el, ...) fn(__VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_7(fn, __VA_ARGS__)), el)
#define FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_7(fn, el, ...) fn(__VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_8(fn, __VA_ARGS__)), el)
#define FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_8(fn, el, ...) fn(__VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_9(fn, __VA_ARGS__)), el)
#define FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_9(fn, el, ...) fn(__VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_10(fn, __VA_ARGS__)), el)
#define FOR_EACH_R_IMPL_10(...) FOR_EACH_ERROR("Shenanigans!")


#define MY_FUNC(nested, var) (nested | var)
#define NEST_RECURSIVE(...) FOR_EACH_R(MY_FUNC, __VA_ARGS__)

NEST_RECURSIVE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G)
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/E7nv15Ms8)

this is easier to understand & also very easy to expand (just add more macros)

###### 4.2 recursive left fold

If you want a recursive version to reduce the number of lines you need to write, you could accomplish that by using a left fold, e.g.:

```cpp
// Recursive Left Fold
#define FOR_EACH_L(fn, ...) __VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_APPLY0(FOR_EACH_RESULT, FOR_EACH_L_4(fn,,__VA_ARGS__)))

#define FOR_EACH_L_4(fn, res, ...) FOR_EACH_APPLY4(FOR_EACH_L_3, FOR_EACH_APPLY4(FOR_EACH_L_3, FOR_EACH_APPLY4(FOR_EACH_L_3, fn, res __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__))))
#define FOR_EACH_L_3(fn, res, ...) FOR_EACH_APPLY3(FOR_EACH_L_2, FOR_EACH_APPLY3(FOR_EACH_L_2, FOR_EACH_APPLY3(FOR_EACH_L_2, fn, res __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__))))
#define FOR_EACH_L_2(fn, res, ...) FOR_EACH_APPLY2(FOR_EACH_L_1, FOR_EACH_APPLY2(FOR_EACH_L_1, FOR_EACH_APPLY2(FOR_EACH_L_1, fn, res __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__))))
#define FOR_EACH_L_1(fn, res, ...) FOR_EACH_APPLY1(FOR_EACH_L_0, FOR_EACH_APPLY1(FOR_EACH_L_0, FOR_EACH_APPLY1(FOR_EACH_L_0, fn, res __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__))))
#define FOR_EACH_L_0(fn, res, ...) fn, FOR_EACH_FIRST(__VA_OPT__(fn(res, FOR_EACH_FIRST(__VA_ARGS__)), ) res) __VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_TAIL(__VA_ARGS__))

#define FOR_EACH_APPLY4(fn, ...) fn(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_APPLY3(fn, ...) fn(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_APPLY2(fn, ...) fn(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_APPLY1(fn, ...) fn(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_APPLY0(fn, ...) fn(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_FIRST(el, ...) el
#define FOR_EACH_TAIL(el, ...) __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_RESULT(fn, res, ...) res
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/o58dET56q)

Left-folds are easier to implement than right-folds, because getting the first element of `__VA_ARGS__` is a lot easier than getting the last one (`FOR_EACH_FIRST` in the above example).

The version provided above can handle up to 81 parameters, if you need more just create more versions of the `FOR_EACH_L_*` & `FOR_EACH_APPLY*` macros. (each additional one of those macros triples the max number of arguments it can handle)

You do need to provide the arguments in reverse order though, since it's a left fold, e.g.:

```cpp
NEST_RECURSIVE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G)
// would result in ((((((( | A) | B) | C) | D) | E) | F) | G)
```

If you need a right fold you could implement it by reversing the arguments and then calling the left fold variant we created above.

e.g.:

```cpp
// Reverse args
#define PARENS ()

#define EXPAND(...) EXPAND4(EXPAND4(EXPAND4(EXPAND4(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND4(...) EXPAND3(EXPAND3(EXPAND3(EXPAND3(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND3(...) EXPAND2(EXPAND2(EXPAND2(EXPAND2(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND2(...) EXPAND1(EXPAND1(EXPAND1(EXPAND1(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND1(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define REVERSE(...) __VA_OPT__(EXPAND(REVERSE_HELPER(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define REVERSE_HELPER(el, ...) __VA_OPT__(REVERSE_AGAIN PARENS (__VA_ARGS__), ) el
#define REVERSE_AGAIN() REVERSE_HELPER
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/xvcM1TG3d)

(this also only works for up to 81 arguments, you can add more `EXPAND*` macros to increase the number of args it can handle)

example:

```cpp
REVERSE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G)
// would result in G, F, E, D, C, B, A
```

and then you could implement the right fold like this:

```cpp
// Right fold
#define FOR_EACH_R(fn, ...) __VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_R_APPLY(FOR_EACH_L, fn, REVERSE(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define FOR_EACH_R_APPLY(fn, ...) fn(__VA_ARGS__)
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/9jfce4xcb)

which finally gives you the expected result (for up to 81 arguments), e.g.:

```cpp
NEST_RECURSIVE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G)
// would result in: ((((((( | G) | F) | E) | D) | C) | B) | A)
```

Full Code: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9jfce4xcb)

```cpp
// Reverse args
#define PARENS ()

#define EXPAND(...) EXPAND4(EXPAND4(EXPAND4(EXPAND4(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND4(...) EXPAND3(EXPAND3(EXPAND3(EXPAND3(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND3(...) EXPAND2(EXPAND2(EXPAND2(EXPAND2(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND2(...) EXPAND1(EXPAND1(EXPAND1(EXPAND1(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND1(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define REVERSE(...) __VA_OPT__(EXPAND(REVERSE_HELPER(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define REVERSE_HELPER(el, ...) __VA_OPT__(REVERSE_AGAIN PARENS (__VA_ARGS__), ) el
#define REVERSE_AGAIN() REVERSE_HELPER

// Recursive Left Fold
#define FOR_EACH_L(fn, ...) __VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_APPLY0(FOR_EACH_RESULT, FOR_EACH_L_4(fn,,__VA_ARGS__)))

#define FOR_EACH_L_4(fn, res, ...) FOR_EACH_APPLY4(FOR_EACH_L_3, FOR_EACH_APPLY4(FOR_EACH_L_3, FOR_EACH_APPLY4(FOR_EACH_L_3, fn, res __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__))))
#define FOR_EACH_L_3(fn, res, ...) FOR_EACH_APPLY3(FOR_EACH_L_2, FOR_EACH_APPLY3(FOR_EACH_L_2, FOR_EACH_APPLY3(FOR_EACH_L_2, fn, res __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__))))
#define FOR_EACH_L_2(fn, res, ...) FOR_EACH_APPLY2(FOR_EACH_L_1, FOR_EACH_APPLY2(FOR_EACH_L_1, FOR_EACH_APPLY2(FOR_EACH_L_1, fn, res __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__))))
#define FOR_EACH_L_1(fn, res, ...) FOR_EACH_APPLY1(FOR_EACH_L_0, FOR_EACH_APPLY1(FOR_EACH_L_0, FOR_EACH_APPLY1(FOR_EACH_L_0, fn, res __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__))))
#define FOR_EACH_L_0(fn, res, ...) fn, FOR_EACH_FIRST(__VA_OPT__(fn(res, FOR_EACH_FIRST(__VA_ARGS__)), ) res) __VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_TAIL(__VA_ARGS__))

#define FOR_EACH_APPLY4(fn, ...) fn(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_APPLY3(fn, ...) fn(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_APPLY2(fn, ...) fn(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_APPLY1(fn, ...) fn(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_APPLY0(fn, ...) fn(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_FIRST(el, ...) el
#define FOR_EACH_TAIL(el, ...) __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_RESULT(fn, res, ...) res

// Right fold
#define FOR_EACH_R(fn, ...) __VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_R_APPLY(FOR_EACH_L, fn, REVERSE(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define FOR_EACH_R_APPLY(fn, ...) fn(__VA_ARGS__)

// For testing
#define MY_FUNC(nested, var) (nested | var)
#define NEST_RECURSIVE(...) FOR_EACH_R(MY_FUNC, __VA_ARGS__)


NEST_RECURSIVE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! Your explanation was very enlightening. It's kind of sad to see that the exponential increase of the max parameter count per SLOC as seen with non-nested "modern" loops isn't possible here, since that was my favorite aspect of them. But nonetheless, thank you very much for taking the time to write this up!

Comment: @Salvage a recursive solution is definitely possible if that's what you're looking for. But you would have to split it into two parts: a left fold (which is easier to implement than a right fold in macros) and an extra macro for reversing the arguments. [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/613Trrdhe) but it's rather complicated in comparison to just copy pasting the same line and replacing the numbers (like in my answer)

Comment: That example only works up to 27 atm, but you can easily add more `FOR_EACH_L_*`, `FOR_EACH_APPLY*` and `EXPAND*` macros to increase its max args count.

Comment: So if I'm not mistaken this exhibits exponential increase in argument count per SLOC as well? This is fantastic! Thank you so much again!!

Comment: @Salvage yes, exactly :) The version in the godbolt is only good up to 27 arguments, but you can triple it's capacity for each additional macro you add. I've updated my answer to include the recursive version as well, with godbolt examples :)

Comment: @Salvage Oh wow, thanks for the additional 100 rep bounty, that's awesome <3 I had a lot of fun piecing together those macros :D Hopefully they solved the problem you're currently working on :)

Comment: They definitely did, and you definitely deserve that bounty!!