# How to understand the usage of #define directive in this code example?

Tags: c++

I am looking into the `#define` directive recently. And I am confused by the #define usage in the following code example. Anyone could explain how it works?

```
template <>
__inline__ __device__ void warpReduce<ReduceType::kSum, 2>(float* val_list) {
  float val0_tmp, val1_tmp;
#define WarpReduceSumOneStep(a, b)                               \
  val0_tmp = __shfl_xor_sync(FINAL_MASK, *(val_list + 0), a, b); \
  val1_tmp = __shfl_xor_sync(FINAL_MASK, *(val_list + 1), a, b); \
  *(val_list + 0) += val0_tmp;                                   \
  *(val_list + 1) += val1_tmp

  WarpReduceSumOneStep(16, 32);
  WarpReduceSumOneStep(8, 32);
  WarpReduceSumOneStep(4, 32);
  WarpReduceSumOneStep(2, 32);
  WarpReduceSumOneStep(1, 32);

#undef WarpReduceSumOneStep
}
```

from my understanding, when `WarpReduceSumOneStep(16, 32);` occurs, the compiler substitute it with the blocks between `#define` and `#undef`, right?

Comment: When `WarpReduceSumOneStep(16, 32);` is encountered in the compiler's preprocessor phase, the macro is expanded using token substitution.  The `#undef` is removing the function-like macro from the macro table at that point in the source code, just to be tidy in case someone uses that same identifier later.

Comment: Just a note instead of diving into the uses of #define have a look at function templates or lambda functions. They would IMO be  better solutions then using macros. And I am not the only one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every preprocessor directive takes up exactly one line. That `\` at the ends of some of the lines say "pretend that this isn't really the end of a line". So the definition of the macro `WarpReduceSumOneStep` includes the next four source lines. They're highlighted in blue on my system. The macro definition ends at the end of that last line, because it doesn't have a `\`; the end of the line really is the end of the line.

After the end of the macro definition, any use of the macro `WarpReduceSumOneStep` gets replaced by the text in the macro's definition. In the code in the question, that macro is used five times:

```
WarpReduceSumOneStep(16, 32);
WarpReduceSumOneStep(8, 32);
WarpReduceSumOneStep(4, 32);
WarpReduceSumOneStep(2, 32);
WarpReduceSumOneStep(1, 32);
```

Each of those is replaced by the text of the macro, with arguments replaced appropriately. I'm not going to go through all five; they're pretty much the same. The first one, `WarpReduceSumOneStep(16, 32)`, becomes

```
val0_tmp = __shfl_xor_sync(FINAL_MASK, *(val_list + 0), 16, 32);
val1_tmp = __shfl_xor_sync(FINAL_MASK, *(val_list + 1), 16, 32);
*(val_list + 0) += val0_tmp;
*(val_list + 1) += val1_tmp
```

and because there's a semicolon after the inovocation of the macro, the full text becomes

```
val0_tmp = __shfl_xor_sync(FINAL_MASK, *(val_list + 0), 16, 32);
val1_tmp = __shfl_xor_sync(FINAL_MASK, *(val_list + 1), 16, 32);
*(val_list + 0) += val0_tmp;
*(val_list + 1) += val1_tmp;
```

After those five uses of the macro, the `#undef` removes its definition. After that, any use of the name `WarpReduceSumOneStep` is just a use of that name; the preprocessor won't do anything special with it.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly. #define sets up the 'keyword reference' of WarpReduceSumOneStep, which is the first part that is

```
WarpReduceSumOneStep(a, b)                               \
  val0_tmp = __shfl_xor_sync(FINAL_MASK, *(val_list + 0), a, b); \
  val1_tmp = __shfl_xor_sync(FINAL_MASK, *(val_list + 1), a, b); \
  *(val_list + 0) += val0_tmp;                                   \
  *(val_list + 1) += val1_tmp
```

Then that section of code uses that expansion 5 times in the 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 uses.
Then the #undef essentially removes that 'keyword reference' so that other parts of that file or linked source / header files could not use it.