# Is it possible to share a common macro in both C++ and python setup.py within a pybind11 project

Tags: python, c++, macros, include, pybind11

I am working on a pybind11 project, and hope both c++ and setup.py on the python can use a commonly defined macro or variable.

for example, in a c++ include file defined.h

```
#define THIS_NAME
#define THIS_NAME1 this_name
```

in python, setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from distutils.command.bdist import bdist as _bdist
from distutils.command.sdist import sdist as _sdist
import pybind11

# The following is for GCC compiler only.
cpp_args = []

a_name = THIS_NAME
if THIS_NAME1 == 'this_name':
   ...
```

Is this doable, and how to implement?

Comment: What makes you think using MACRO's is a good idea in the first place? See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives). Instead of using a macro define a typed constant and have a C++ function that returns that value so python can pick it up.

Comment: I am not limiting myself to use MACRO.  Let me make it clear. The python file I refer to actually is the setup.py.

Comment: You would have to do something like `re.findall('#define (\w+) (\w+)', <CONTENTS-OF-FILE>)`. But normally you would pass the defined variable from python to C++ by adding `-DTHIS_NAME=this_name` to the `extra_compile_args` argument of `Extension`.