# How to pass generic arguments to the nested generic classes in C++

Tags: c++, generics

I have a class and a nested class in C++ and they are both generic classes.

```
#define GENERIC template<typename T>
    
GENERIC
class Class1 final{
private:
    GENERIC
    class Class2 final{
    private:
        T class2Field{};
    };

    T class1Field{};
};
```

I want to pass the type parameter `T` that is passed to `Class1` when instantiating it, all the way to the `Class 2`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: The first step is to _stop using macros_.

Comment: By not using an idiosyncratic macro that creates your own *limited* C++ subset. Spell out the template introducer, and give each parameter its own name. Then you can use those names freely. This question is akin to the joke about the man going to the doctor and complaining "it hurts when I do this weird thing", so the doctor of course responds with "well then, don't do this weird thing".

Comment: No need to use macro here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class2` can see the declaration of `Class1`, therefore will use `Class1`'s `T` when not declared a templated class:

```
template<typename T>
class Class1 final {
private:
    class Class2 final {
    private:
        T class2Field{};
    };

    T class1Field{};
};
```

so `Class1<int>::Class2::class2Field` will be of type `int`.

---

If you want `Class2` still to be a templated class, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74547125/6039995).

---

better not use macros: [Why are preprocessor macros evil and what are the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives).

Comment: The  question says that both class are generics. In your answer, nested class is not templated.

Comment: correct, I edited it.

Comment: Instead of making your answer same as [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74547125/12002570), you could've just added a link to my answer saying something like if `Class2` is also a template then refer to that answer.

Comment: I edited before you posted, I can rollback, sure.

Comment: Our answer can be complementary to each other. That way there will be no conflict as technically my answer was posted slightly before your edit for the same. Both answer can be helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

> How to pass generic arguments to the nested generic classes in C++

Since the nested class is also templated, you can make use of default argument as shown below:

```
template<typename T>
class Class1 {
private:
//-----------vvvvvvvvvvvvvv---->use default argument
    template<typename U = T>
    class Class2 {
    private:
        U class2Field{};
    };

    T class1Field{};
};
```

Now `Class1<int>::Class2::class2Field` will be of type `int`.