# How to expand a Boolean expression in the C++ preprocessor?

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor, expansion

The following code does not expand the Boolean expression, see also https://godbolt.org/z/YqbazT3eo:

```cpp
#define EXPAND(x) x

#define SWITCH false
EXPAND(SWITCH || defined(_DEBUG))
```

How do I do it correctly so that I can do

```cpp
#define FLAG EXPAND(SWITCH || defined(_DEBUG))
```

(or similar) and `FLAG` will not depend on later changes to `SWITCH`?

Comment: What do you mean by "later changes"?

Comment: @PasserBy redefinitions, for instance.

Comment: For me this question smells like [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). In [C++ macros are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14041453/1387438) and they should be avoided as much as possible, used only as last resort. Since you didn't describe why you need this (X-problem) it is impossible to tell if your approach (Y-problem) is a proper approach. I can imagine this can be addressed using `constexpr` or on other side by some feature of build manager.

Comment: @MarekR "it is impossible to tell if your approach (Y-problem) is a proper approach" - that is fine, since I never asked for that :)

Comment: @bers That is nature "XY problem", incorrectly stated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `FLAG` will not depend on later changes to SWITCH?

The only way is this:

```
#if SWITCH || defined(_DEBUG)
#define FLAG 1
#else
#define FLAG 0
#endif
```

Comment: I feared so. Any reason *why* this is the only way?

Comment: @bers Because `#define` is lazy, the replacement string is stored as is. It's only looked at when the macro is expanded.

Comment: To understand better why this is the only way, you'll need to understand the difference between the preprocessor (which only expands preprocessor directives to produce source code, and doesn't use C++ language syntax, keywords, etc) and [in most implementations] the "compiler", which takes the output of the preprocessor.   Most basic texts on C++ explain the difference - the fact you expect otherwise shows you haven't bothered to read introductory material.

Comment: @Peter I mean, preprocessor can interpret boolean expressions, otherwise `#if` wouldn't work. But there's no way to force it to do it outside of an `#if`.

Comment: True.  My previous comment was directed more at @bers though.    The question as asked here was "how do I do it?".   Explaining why (as per later query/comment) is possible, but wouldn't make sense to someone who doesn't understand the difference between the preprocessor and later phases of translation (including the "compiler").

Comment: @Peter your comments are rude and incorrect. In fact, SO has plenty of questions on macro expansion that go well beyond "introductory material", with rather obscure definitions such as `#define macro_helper(x) macro(x)`. A more helpful comment could have been that "`defined` is not macro (name)`.

Answer (score 1):

The C/C++ preprocessor is dumb when not handling conditionals; it only expands whatever is `#define`d, and don't care about the rest – meaning it has no ability to deduce that something is a constant expression and evaluate it. Also `defined()` only hold special meaning in `#if` directives and friends.

Redefinitions later in a file would emit a warning in modern compilers, but before the redefinition the macro still expands to the old value. Thus

```cpp
#define EXPAND(x) x

#define SWITCH false
EXPAND(SWITCH || defined(_DEBUG))

#define SWITCH true
```

expands to the following (GCC 13.2):

```cpp
false || defined(_DEBUG)
```