function name collides with function in windows.h
Porting a library of my own making from Macintosh to Windows, it looks like I've bumped up against a predefined symbol in Windows:
[build] In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/windows.h:72,
[build]                  from C:/Users/ken/Desktop/Drawbox/Library/Win/Drawbox.Win.cpp:31:
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/include/winuser.h:3766:29: error: ambiguating new declaration of 'HICON__* GetCursor()'
[build]  3766 |   WINUSERAPI HCURSOR WINAPI GetCursor(VOID);
[build]       |                             ^~~~~~~~~
[build] In file included from C:/Users/ken/Desktop/Drawbox/Library/Win/Drawbox.Win.cpp:15:
[build] C:/Users/ken/Desktop/Drawbox/Library/Drawbox.h:559:5: note: old declaration 'int GetCursor()'
[build]   559 | int GetCursor();
[build]       |     ^~~~~~~~~

Well, I really don't want the one defined by Windows, I would be very happy to hide it with the one I'm defining. So I tried:
#define GetCursor() GetCursorX()
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#undef GetCursor

But no, this makes the compiler even more unhappy:
[  6%] [32mBuilding CXX object CMakeFiles/TestProgram.dir/Library/Win/Drawbox.Win.cpp.obj[0m
[build] In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/windows.h:72,
[build]                  from C:/Users/ken/Desktop/Drawbox/Library/Win/Drawbox.Win.cpp:32:
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/include/winuser.h:3766:43: error: macro "GetCursor" passed 1 arguments, but takes just 0
[build]  3766 |   WINUSERAPI HCURSOR WINAPI GetCursor(VOID);
[build]       |                                           ^
[build] C:/Users/ken/Desktop/Drawbox/Library/Win/Drawbox.Win.cpp:31: note: macro "GetCursor" defined here
[build]    31 | #define GetCursor() GetCursorX()

Is this doable, or am I just stuck renaming my function to work around Windows?

The best solution would (IMHO) be to just have all your libraries functions in a library specific namespace. mylibrary::GetCursor() wouldn't clash.

An alternative approach is to not include the Windows header files into your code, except at your code's abstraction "edge", which acts as a firewall between your code and Windows (or Macintosh or whatever other platform).  The standard C++ library acts as a "edge" abstraction for some things, such as the file system or threading.  But the standard C++ library doesn't have a clue about cursors.

Can we talk you into replacing your GetCursor macro with an inline function? They are generally easier to debug, compile down to no overhead, AND you can put them in a namespace as suggested by Jesper Juhl.

Side note: I generally write a portability layer that wraps disparate target-specific functionality inside a common and portable API and then exclusively use the portability layer. The build system links in the implementation of the layer used for a particular target.

Answer: many of the functions defined in windows.h are actually macros that resolve to some related name with a suffix. So windows.h gets very unhappy if you try to redefine its macros, but it works fine to undefined them afterward:
#include <windows.h> 
#include <mmsystem.h>
#undef GetCursor

Worked like a charm.

Sadly, there will be those that point to this as one good reason to use the pre-processor to redefine API names :-\  Any chance wrapping a namespace around the other library could have worked (assuming you have the source)?

Preprocessor macros are The Devil™.

@franji1 -- macros don't respect namespaces.

@Eljay, can you elaborate or point to a reference explaining why they are The Devil™?

@stackaccount • q.v. https://stackoverflow.com/q/14041453/4641116
